# Retornar todos os dados em um mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma consulta que retorna os dados abaixo:

```
nome -------- vencimento   
Joao -------- 09/08/2012   
Maria ------- 04/12/2015
```

Ou seja, **dois registros**.

Porém, ao colocá-la no código PHP apenas o registro superior é retornado, mesmo utilizando `+=` e uma estrutura `while` no `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

**Código PHP**

```
 $result = array();


    $sql_select = mysql_query(
        "SELECT nome, vencimento
        FROM alunos"
    )or die(mysql_error());

    while($l = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_select)){
        $result += $l;        
    }



return json_encode($result);
```

**Retorno $result atual**:

```
{"nome":"Joao","vencimento":"09/08/2012"}
```

**Retorno $result esperado**:

```
   {"nome":"Joao","vencimento":"09/08/2012"}
   {"nome":"Maria","vencimento":"04/12/2015"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+=` não funciona para adicionar um item em um array, faça a atribuição com colchetes.

Mude:

```
while($l = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_select)){
    $result += $l;        
}
```

Para:

```
while($l = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_select)){
    $result[]= $l;        
}
```

Comment: Funcionou @rray, mas sabe me dizer porque isso acontece?